# C# Many URL requests, takes long time for processing

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I have to send around 120 URL requests to the following URL

```
HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=" + keyword + "&c=apps&hl=en");
```

Where Keyword is different in each request, I get the page in response, process the page and extract the Count of Apps from the response page, which includes string manipulation. But it takes more than a minutes to process these 120 requests.

I am thinking for Multithreading but at same time, Can you suggest some thing more efficient so I reduce the time to max 1-2 seconds.

Comment: It's not a surprise that it takes some time to do this...  Creating web requests requires some extra handshaking and I suppose the total operation would be around 500ms - 1s each.  You mentioned using multithreading...  Can you post an example of what you have tried and the results?  I'm sure the community could help if you get stuck with the implementation.

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to complete 120 requests in 1-2 seconds. But even if you have resources for that, i think Google will block you, for such amount of connects

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate community response. But I want to implement multithreading, i need your suggestion. I have two main tasks i) Fetch Data from URL using Web Request ii) Process data, string manipulations etc... Thing is if I make two threads for each of these tasks, but second task will have to wait for input of the first thread so its kinda useless. Or can you suggest what I can do best in this situation? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It unlikely you'll get the processing time down to 1-2 seconds. Sure, you might be able to cut some time off here and there through optimisation, and bits of it will be hardware- and Internet connection-limited.

Aside from have a many-core processor and using a load of threads, the time won't cut down that much. Multithreading is probably your best bet, but you won't get a 300-600% performance improvement that way.

Answer (score 0):

Do the calls asynchronously by calling `GetResponseAsync` instead of `GetResponse`. This allows you to send several requests at the same time. But keep in mind that the number of requests that can be processed at the same time is limited. So you will only get a limited speed increase, but it's worth trying it.

Processing the result of the request takes only a little portion of the total time. The big part is consumed by the communication, so doing the processing of the result with multithreading will not help much.

Comment: Hi, I didn't find GetResponseAsync method, I saw I am using .net 4.0 and probably it is supported in higher versions of .net

Comment: Yes. `GetResponseAsync` was introduced with .NET Framework 4.5.  There is also the [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.90).aspx) method, which is a bit more difficult to use but also works asynchonously.